# How to best pack integers into RGBA using Python3 and then unpack it

Tags: python, glsl, pixel, pack, rgba

I'm trying to save 32 bit integer into pixels in a bitmap.
How to store this example value 98603205 into rgba channels 0-255 each using Python3? (The big numbers is not colors, but addresses in a data structure.)

And then unpack the value from pixels into a integer?

I wishes for a small code example in python3
Best Regards

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post what you have tried so far ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "bitmap"? Do you mean a BMP file? I don't know what file formats are available to WebGL, but there has to be more than just BMPs, right?

Comment: As long as the format does not compress the pixels or distort the data in any way. Remember in this case it is not colors but addresses to be stored in the pixels. So when the value is unpacked it must be exactly the same. Both PNG and BMP work probably fine. I can load the image in the browser using JS "new Image()" object. And then use gl.texImage2D() to load image to gpu. Best option for WebGL is 4 channels RGBA whit 4 UNSIGNED_BYTE for each pixel.

Comment: My first naive python attempt was to convert the number (ex. "98056210") to a string and then group them two by two into a list. Ex. [98, 05, 62, 10]. And to solve the problem of pairs starting with zero, I increase the first number in each group ex [108, 15, 72, 20]. Then used the PIL to write pixels. The maximum value with this attempt is 99999999. And not so easy to unpack ... Need better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first part of the solution, integer to 4x255 color channels using bitwise operations in python

```
    import random  
    # create random integer to test pack and unpack
    nrToUnpack = random.randint(0,4294967295)  

    # create bitwize masks for color channels  
    redMask = 0xFF000000  
    greenMask = 0xFF0000  
    blueMask = 0xFF00  
    alphaMask = 0xFF  
    print("not unpacked yet", nrToUnpack)  

    # bitwize mask the integer into 8-bits each  
    red = (nrToUnpack & redMask) >> 24  
    green = (nrToUnpack & greenMask) >> 16  
    blue = (nrToUnpack & blueMask) >> 8  
    alpha = (nrToUnpack & alphaMask)  

    # each channel 0-255  
    print("unpacked", red, green, blue, alpha)  

    # bitwize repack the integer  
    numberPacked = alpha | (blue << 8) | (green << 16) | (red << 24)  
    print("repacked again", numberPacked)
```

Max value to store is 4294967295
Next part is to unpack this in GLSL. Any suggestions?